# How to navigate into a subdirectory whose name is not known in Unix?

Tags: linux, unix, directory

We have a typical directory structure,and we need to navigate into a directory.
The problem is the name of the directory changes every time and I am trying to do that by using a script. Below is the directory structure

```
/home/km5001731/cxs/ratc/1670/RATC1670/xxxxx
```

I want to navigate into that "xxxxx" directory and I do not know the name of that directory, and there are some more directories present inside that, and I know the names of those directories.

How can I navigate to the one I want?

Comment: If there's more than one sub-directory under the RATC1670 directory, how do you know which one to use this time?  What's the criteria?  Or is there just one directory in RATC1670 but there are multiple directories within that one?  Your question is ambiguous between the two scenarios.  Are there any files also in the RATC1670 directory?

Comment: I interpreted the problem as "I know which directories it isn't but not which directory it is". Rereading the question though, I realize that the problem more likely is "I don't know the name of the folder, but I know what is in it." I will change my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing below we can navigate to the current sub directory

## !/bin/bash

cd /home/km5001731/cxs/ratc/1670/RATC1670/
Out_dir=`ls -Art | tail -n 1`
cd /home/km5001731/cxs/ratc/1670/RATC1670/$Out_dir

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to find all directories available

```
find /home/km5001731/cxs/ratc/1670/RATC1670/ -type d -maxdepth 1
```

Then, you can iterate through them looking for the one in question

```
#!/bin/bash
base_path='/home/km5001731/cxs/ratc/1670/RATC1670/'
correct_directory=''
for directory in $(find "$base_path" -type d -maxdepth 1)
do
        subdirectories=$(find "${directory}" -type d -maxdepth 1)
        if grep -q "known_dir1" <<< "$subdirectories" && grep -q "known_dir2" <<< "$subdirectories"
        then
                correct_directory="${directory}"
                break
        fi
done
if [[ "$correct_directory" = "" ]]
then
        echo "Didn't find it!"
        exit
fi
cd "$correct_directory"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can write a small piece of C code recursively calling opendir() and readdir() with regular expression argument for exclusive or inclusive folder name pattern

```
void examinedir(char *dir, RegExp p)
{
        DIR *dp;
        struct dirent *entry;
        struct stat statbuf;

        if((dp=opendir(dir))== NULL)
        {
                //Error
                return;
        }


        while(entry=readdir(dp))
        {
                char abspath[256] = {0};
                sprintf(abspath, "%s/%s",dir,entry->d_name);
                lstat(abspath, &statbuf);
                if(S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode))
                {
                        // It is folder, examine it with p
                        // call examinedir(abspath,p) if you want
                }
                else
                {
                        // file
                }
        }

        closedir(dp);
}
```